# Automation of SSIS package developed in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, visual-studio-2015, ssis

Can someone please explain the best way to automate a SSIS package that was built in Visual Studio 2015 without using the SQL Agent? Preferably in Task Scheduler. I have tried using the older technique of dtexec but I kept receiving a version error message. I then tried running dtexec as a batch file and it could not locate the dtexec file. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the script I tried using:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dtexec /f "C:\Users\amoberg\Documents\Scripts\DailyCancel\DailyCancel\Package.dtsx"
```

Thank you

UPDATE:
Here is the CMD error:

> C:>dtexec /F "C:\Scripts\DailyCancel\DailyCancel\Package.dtsx"
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 11.0.6020.0
>   for 32-bit Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Started:  12:42:33 PM Error: 2017-01-05 12:42:33.92    Code:
>   0xC001700A    Source: Package    Description: The version number in
>   the package is not valid. The version number cannot be greater than
>   current version number. End Error Error: 2017-01-05 12:42:33.93
>   Code: 0xC0016020    Source: Package    Description: Package migration
>   from version 8 to version 6 failed with error 0xC001700A "The version
>   number in the package is not valid. The version number cannot be
>   greater than current version number.". End Error Error: 2017-01-05
>   12:42:33.93    Code: 0xC0010018    Source: Package    Description:
>   Error loading value "8" from node
>   "DTS:Property". End Error Could not load package
>   "C:\Scripts\DailyCancel\DailyCancel\Package.dtsx" because of error
>   0xC0010014. Description: The package failed to load due to error
>   0xC0010014 "One or more error occurred. There should be more specific
>   errors preceding this one that explains the details of the errors.
>   This message is used as a return value from functions that encounter
>   errors.". This occurs when CPackage::LoadFromXML fails. Source:
>   Package Started:  12:42:33 PM Finished: 12:42:33 PM Elapsed:  0.094
>   seconds

Comment: You have spaces in the path... try using quotes like this "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\dtexec"

Comment: Is SSIS installed and active? If so, what SQL Server version is installed?

Comment: Yes, SSIS is installed and active. Using SQL Server version 2016. It runs fine within Visual Studio 2015, but when I try automating it I run into issues. I also tried what RGuggisberg suggested but it still did not work...

Comment: I would try powershell to execute a t-sql statement, that is if you are at least publishing to the ssis catalog.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute a package from SSIS 2014 or higher with a dtexec from SSIS 2012. The error posted is saying that package version is newer (higher) that SSIS server version. Check yourself with exact path and version number; presumably, you have both SSIS 2012 and 2014+ on your server.
To fix this issue, select path of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\ <your version of SQL and SSIS> \DTS\Binn`, run dtexec with your parameters. This should execute your package.